# How to disable EditorFor item from time to time daily?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I disable the item Editor for and enable writing only from 4pm to 11:59 pm in an ASP.NET MVC view?

This is the control markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

How to use:

```
If Datetime.Now between 16:00 and 23:59
```

then enable the item, else disable it.

Comment: Do you mean that the `DateTime.Now` is the current time on the client computer? Take to account the `DateTime.Now` is the c# property and the c# code is running on the server side.

Comment: @Jackdaw I need to check local country time the system will used in more than one computer so I need to use it depends on Saudi Arabia local time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this For example in View

```
   @{ 
  TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0); 
    TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(23, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    }
    
    if ((now > start) && (now < end))
    {
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",disabled= "disabled" } })
 
    
    }
    else{
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
    
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much its working :) I need your help also if there is any issue in coming days

Comment: can you help me brother in this error how to solve it please or if you have another way how to insert multiple rows into database  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76337895/why-i-got-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-source