# why I got error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to populate the CREATE view with data templates from table

as Jeremy said I updated the code added List and used for loop with Editor for the CREATE view :

```
@model List<warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS",FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Department name</th>
                <th>Test name</th>
                <th>Total tests morning</th>
                <th>Total tests evening</th>
                <th>Hospital name</th>
                <th>user name</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>


            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].DEPT_ID)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].TEST_ID)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].TESTS_MORNING )</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].TESTS_EVENING)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].hospital_no )</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].user_id )</td>

            </tr>
        }
      
     

    </table>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

   
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and this is the create actions get and post :

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
           ViewBag.DEPT_ID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Dept_id", "Dept_name");
            ViewBag.hospital_no = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "Id", "hospital_name");
            ViewBag.TEST_ID = new SelectList(db.LabTests_hajj, "TestId", "TestName");
            ViewBag.user_id = new SelectList(db.sys_users, "user_id", "user_name");
            return View();
            
        }

       
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SID,DEPT_ID,TEST_ID,TESTS_MORNING,TESTS_EVENING,DATE,hospital_no,user_id")] DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.Add(dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

           ViewBag.DEPT_ID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Dept_id", "Dept_name", dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.DEPT_ID);
            ViewBag.hospital_no = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "Id", "hospital_name", dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.hospital_no);
           ViewBag.TEST_ID = new SelectList(db.LabTests_hajj, "TestId", "TestName", dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.TEST_ID);
           ViewBag.user_id = new SelectList(db.sys_users, "user_id", "user_name", dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.user_id);
            return View(dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS);
        }
```

when I click create button it show error

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

on the `

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)`

How I will update the create action to accept List

the table by default null no data I will insert data from this create view

controller action will need to accept a List ?

Comment: You can bind a `List<T>` (or other collection type) as your model. eg `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items[i].TESTS_MORNING, ...)`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman can you please add answer the create view how I will do it

Comment: There's plenty of official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#expression-names-and-collections

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I changed the create view can you see updated question last edit but I got error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
when click create button how to solve this please ?

Comment: Instead of setting a ViewBag property, use `return View(dept_temp)` and fix the `@model` declaration (probably `List<DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS_TEMPLATE>`). Then use `foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I need to read the default data values from DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS_TEMPLATE table then Insert it into the main table DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS after add the values for this reason I did the ViewBag I made the updates you add but show error in foreach (var item in Model) foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS I know this is not the default way but how can I do that ?

Comment: The type of @model must match the type of dept_temp, which apparently is some List

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I updated the views and actions in question can you take a look please and how to match model with dept_temp thank you

Comment: By the way (I didn't notice earlier), a "create" page is usually used to ask for new data, which is added to the table on submit (POST). So why would you show a list there anyway, and why don't you have any input fields?

Comment: What *is* the data type of dept_temp? @model should have the same type

Comment: @HansKeﬆing variable I created it in create action to store the data var dept_temp = db.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS_TEMPLATE.Include(d => d.Department).Include(d => d.Hospital).Include(d => d.LabTests_hajj).Include(d => d.sys_users).ToList();

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I need to show the list it will be the input fields is this correct way ? I have another way I used it now but it is not good practice which is to insert the default data into the table then show it and edit it only not insert

Comment: Yes, I saw where you created that variable. But `var` is an instruction to the compiler to figure out the type. You can hover over "var" or the variable (one or the other) to see the *actual* type - that's the one you need for @model

Comment: Your view will need a `List<T>`, and your controller action will need to accept a `List<T>`. Your view will need to `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) ... .EditorFor(model => model[i].[Property])` to name all the input boxes so that MVC binding can construct the list and pass it to the controller (as per the link I posted above).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I updated the code as you said but how I will update the controller to accept List<T> can you see the updated question code thank you

Answer (score 0):

why you don't try just this in your foreach
and Check your ViewBag dont be null

```
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.templates)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>@item.Department.dept_name</td>
           <td>@item.LabTests_hajj.TestName</td>
           <td>@item.TESTS_MORNING</td>
           <td>@item.TESTS_EVENING</td>
           <td>@item.Hospital.hospital_name</td>
           <td>@item.sys_users.user_name</td>
       </tr>
   }
```

Comment: I tried it but got this error :  'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Department_D90B27E5DC25178FCAF5B43AE6AB6867AFE0306ADF2F66C887A5654E7C42B609' does not contain a definition for 'dept_name'       <td>@item.Department.dept_name</td>

Comment: see your model..do you have  'dept_name' in your model?or your binding to the ViewBag is not correct

Comment: I removed the columns from ViewBag and selected the columns in the table DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS only and got same error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.